# Selenium firefox webdriver opening skype extension website as a default tab. Tried updating the driver and browser

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

[Selenium firefox webdriver opening skype extension website as a default tab. gecko driver version -geckodriver-v0.14.0,Firefox version -52.0.2 and in control panel i cannot see any skype installtion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioxP1.png)[Skype link which is opening in new tab while invkoing firefox](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34612/what-is-the-skype-extension)
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "test\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
driver =new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Saying you tried everything doesn't really help because we don't know what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I too encountered this issue.Try to use below code(I am creating new firefox profile and invoking browser with that profile).

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restricated", 1);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Let me know if it works for you